# Trying to extract a API request token and wrap my handlers

Tags: go, gorilla

I want to use the new context to wrap my handlers so I can have a User struct available in all my handlers (or whatever else I need for the current request to tell me about who is making the request).

I am getting an error with this:

```
func main() {


router := mux.NewRouter()

  router.HandleFunc("/api/v1/user/{id}", userService.GetUsers).Methods("GET")

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3001", router))
}

func WithAuth(us UserService, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandleFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    auth := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
    if auth == "" {
      next.ServeHTTP(w, r) // continue without token
      return
    }

    // token, err := a.Authorize(auth)
    // if err != nil {
    //   http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusUnauthorized)
    //   return
    // }

    ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "hello", "world")
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
  })
}
```

The error is:

> not enough arguments in call to http.HandleFunc  have
>   (func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request))    want (string,
>   func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)) ./main.go:65:25:
>   http.HandleFunc(func literal) used as value ./main.go:78:12:
>   undefined: context

I tried to adapt the code I read from here: https://gist.github.com/peterbourgon/2d190ddbb8d2cbddb5bceaca80eef20e#file-ctx-go

Comment: Have you imported the "context" package?

Comment: @SohamKamani I did now, and it removed the last error but the others remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing http.HandleFunc & http.Handle**r**Func (note the r)

```
func WithAuth(us UserService, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
      return http.HandleFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
```

but you need to return a http.HandlerFunc instead

```
 func WithAuth(us UserService, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
      return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now if I try and wrap ```userService.GetUsers``` with ```withAuth(us, userService.GetUsers)``` I get an error saying: ```cannot use WithAuth(userService.GetUsers) (type http.Handler) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to router.HandleFunc``` .

Comment: use router.Handle to register the handler rather than router.HandleFunc